# Can't get the right view in a list by view.getTag()

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, view

I have a custom card list view.. the view contains an imageView and three buttons..

What i want to do is when i click on a button i want to set the image of the card that holds that button in imageView object..

What happens is that setSelectedimage() sets the one in the last card in the view holder not the clicked one..

here is my getView code:

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(
                    R.layout.home_card, parent, false);

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            view.setTag(viewHolder);

            viewHolder.imageView = (ImageView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.activity_googlecards_card_imageview);
            viewHolder.favIB = (ImageButton) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.fav_imagebutton);
            viewHolder.editIB = (ImageButton) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.edit_imagebutton);
            viewHolder.shareIB = (ImageButton) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.share_imagebutton);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(imageWidth,imageWidth);
        viewHolder.imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
        viewHolder.imageView.setTag(position);

        OnClickListener myOnClickListener = new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int id = v.getId();
                String msg = " clicked";

                switch (id) {
                case R.id.fav_imagebutton:
                    msg = "favourite" + msg;
                    break;

                case R.id.edit_imagebutton:
                    msg = "edit" + msg;

                    viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
                    System.out.println(viewHolder.imageView.getTag());
                    setSelectedImage(viewHolder.imageView);
                    break;

                case R.id.share_imagebutton:
                    msg = "share" + msg;
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
                }

        };

        viewHolder.favIB.setOnClickListener(myOnClickListener);
        viewHolder.editIB.setOnClickListener(myOnClickListener);
        viewHolder.shareIB.setOnClickListener(myOnClickListener);

        return view;
    }
```

and here is my viewHolder class:

```
private static class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imageView;
        ImageButton favIB;
        ImageButton editIB;
        ImageButton shareIB;
    }
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this line inside your click listener is the issue:

```
viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
```

the `view` received during click is the actual clicked view, meaning on the call `onClick(View v)` for the `case R.id.edit_imagebutton` the `View v` is the `ImageButton editIB` .

So when you ask for the tag of it, there's no tag, because you never set one. You should set the tag to be able to retrieve it.

```
viewHolder.editIB.setTag(viewHolder);


@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(
                R.layout.home_card, parent, false);

        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

        viewHolder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.activity_googlecards_card_imageview);
        viewHolder.favIB = (ImageButton) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.fav_imagebutton);
        viewHolder.editIB = (ImageButton) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.edit_imagebutton);
        viewHolder.editIB.setTag(viewHolder); // THIS
        viewHolder.shareIB = (ImageButton) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.share_imagebutton);


    OnClickListener myOnClickListener = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int id = v.getId();
            String msg = " clicked";

            switch (id) {
            case R.id.fav_imagebutton:
                msg = "favourite" + msg;
                break;

            case R.id.edit_imagebutton:
                msg = "edit" + msg;

                viewHolder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag(); // HERE
                setSelectedImage(viewHolder.imageView);
                break;

            case R.id.share_imagebutton:
                msg = "share" + msg;
                break;

            default:
                break;
            }

    };

    viewHolder.favIB.setOnClickListener(myOnClickListener);
    viewHolder.editIB.setOnClickListener(myOnClickListener);
    viewHolder.shareIB.setOnClickListener(myOnClickListener);

    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(imageWidth,imageWidth);
    viewHolder.imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
    viewHolder.imageView.setTag(position);

    return view;
}
```

Comment: I don't ask for the tag of editIB.. i am asking for the tag of the whole view (view)

Comment: But the view you receive inside `onClick(View v)` is not the whole view. It is the view with id `R.id.edit_imagebutton`

Comment: I just read again your code and I guess I see now the hookie mistake you're doing. You cannot keep a reference to `view` like that. It doesn't work. Because the method `getView` gets called several times by the `ListView`. I edited my answer with a working solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
viewHolder.editIB.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            ImageView iv = viewHolder.imageView;
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //you can use iv here it will get the right image

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 viewHolder.imageView = (ImageView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.activity_googlecards_card_imageview);
```

change to `view.imageView = (ImageView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.activity_googlecards_card_imageview);`

Comment: thanks for your cooperation.. but that didn't work with me :)

Answer (score 0):

You should get View using heirarchy of your layout. This may help you-

```
 viewHolder.imageView.setTag(position);

        OnClickListener myOnClickListener = new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int id = v.getId();
                String msg = " clicked";

                switch (id) {
                case R.id.fav_imagebutton:
                    msg = "favourite" + msg;
                    break;

                case R.id.edit_imagebutton:
                    msg = "edit" + msg;

                    //get sibling view using hierarchy like 
                    EditText et = (EditText)v;

                    // fetch its parent and cast to class whatever it is RelativeLayout or LinearLayout
                    // eg. Relativelayout is edittext' parent in layout                      
                    RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout)et.getParent();

                    // Now get its child named activity_googlecards_card_imageview
                    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rl.findViewById(R.id.activity_googlecards_card_imageview);

                    System.out.println(imageView.getTag());
                    setSelectedImage(imageView);
                    break;

                case R.id.share_imagebutton:
                    msg = "share" + msg;
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
                }

        };

       viewHolder.favIB.setOnClickListener(myOnClickListener);
        viewHolder.editIB.setOnClickListener(myOnClickListener);
        viewHolder.shareIB.setOnClickListener(myOnClickListener);
```

Comment: thanks for your cooperation.. but that didn't work with me :)